# iTunes Tool Bar

Tags: macos, itunes, menu-bar

On my old PC iTunes would come up with a tool bar with headings like File, Edit, Songs View ect. On my new iMac I can not find any place to get this tool bar or the information that it did display

Answer (score 3):

All macOS apps have their menus in the Menu Bar, shown at the top of the screen. Apps in macOS don't attach their menus to a window, but instead show them here.

[image]